# Piping into MySQL slower than redirecting file into stdin?

Tags: mysql

I am importing a 7 gig MySQL dump file into the database. I used this command:

```
cat dumpfile.sql | mysql -u root -D mydatabase -p
```

It is taking a long time! Would this approach have been quicker?

```
mysql -u root -D database -p < dumpfile.sql
```

The command has been running for 1.5 days now - would the second approach save me a significant amount of time?

Comment: The limiting factor is likely MySQL, not the string reading.

Comment: Stop it, start it again with the 2nd approach, and if it takes more than 1.5 days you can say "undecided" ;-) (But seriously, what's the bottleneck?)

Comment: Are you INSERTing into large tables which have indexes? If so you might want to DISABLE KEYS while you do the INSERT: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html

Comment: STOP PIPING CATS!

Comment: (Did you find the problem? Over-transactions?)

Comment: I gave up - it's not a beefy machine, so I'm guessing it was to do with IO. I'm going to revisit the file and use a couple of approaches to get it into the database quicker: put the file being read on a different disk from the database, and perhaps use multiple threads to process the file rather than just the one being used while dumping into MySQL - the machine has multiple cores but a slow main disk...

Comment: @newtover I have to disagree in this case.  I found this question because I was validating my syntax for `sed '1.3d' dumpfile.sql| mysql ... `, a case where using the `<` redirect doesn't help me all that much.  It's a lot more common to see `cat <file> | grep` than my exact use-case.  Almost like it's a standard place-holder for things.  For life.  If he hadn't `|` from that `cat`, my life would never be complete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the two versions are two syntaxes to reach the *same effect*, sending `dumpfile.sql` to stdin of the mysql process, the time they take would be pretty much identical.

The first version starts an extra process - `cat` - which the second approach does not, but you can count on the overhead of `cat` being negligible compared to importing the actual data into mysql.

Comment: and what about speed of mysql> source dumpfile.sql ?